# Convert a DOCX file to XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, docx

I'm trying to create a page with the following function:
The user must select a DOCX file. This file will be read by JavaScript and converted to XML, so I can work with the data in JSON.

Searching the internet, I found posts saying that you just need to unpack the DOCX file to get the XML.
Using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) I unzipped the DOCX file. Now I have a list of 18 objects, all compressed.
In summary: I came back to the beginning of the problem.

I find many posts saying how to convert XML to DOCX or how to convert DOCX to HTML, but to convert DOCX to XML I only find in Java.
How can I get XML from a DOCX file using JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal? XML for the sake of XML does not seem particularly useful. How are you going to process it? What information do you want to extract?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The file that the user selects contains a table with data that must be entered on the page. To work on this data, I'll transform the XML into JSON.  
This part is already done and working. If the user selects an XML file, it will work perfectly. The problem is that I was asked to be a DOCX file instead of an XML.

Comment: ...`converted to XML, so I can work with the data in JSON`... I think you're more confused than we are.

Comment: You might also Google `javascript docx parser`.  Google is a programmer's first stop.

Comment: @SamAxe As I said to Álvaro, my code is already prepared to convert XML into JSON. So no... I know what I need. And I also know Google very well. Unfortunately, all the solutions I've found are libraries that only let you enter the URL to fetch the file on the server, and what I need is to convert the local DOCX file.
But thanks for the tip, despite the highly unnecessary sarcasm.